# Call function in kendo grid column template

Tags: angular, templates, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-template

Hi I would like to know how do I call a function inside the kendo cloumn template?

I would like this function to take the cell value and return a result.

Something like this:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="tot"  [style]="{'text-align': 'right'}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-value="value">
        <span>{{ myFunction(value) }}</span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>



 
public myFunction(n){
   if(n>0){
     return "ok";
  }else{
     return "do check";
  }
}
```

The function is not called in this case.

thanks,

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no field called `value` to be passed.

Try to change:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="tot"  [style]="{'text-align': 'right'}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-value="value">
        <span>{{ myFunction(value) }}</span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

to:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="tot"  [style]="{'text-align': 'right'}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <span>{{ myFunction(dataItem) }}</span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

and use `myFunction` accordingly.

Please read [https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellTemplateDirective](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellTemplateDirective/) to have a better understanding.